# Make a update check on a variable from a Json API

Tags: c#, uwp

So I have a `UWP` project that I handle bookings on a group of rooms in. 
I get all of my values from a `Json API`.

I want to make like a `loop` that checks if a room is booked or not every minute or something like that, but I have no idé how to do it.

This is how I get all the rooms with the bookings and all the attributes to them:

```
public async void addroom()
        {
            string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/company/07ce8f7c-f3d3-4df2-84bd-33f8fc263deb/rooms";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            List<Class2> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(response);

            foreach (Class2 room in data)
            {
                string booking = $"https://api.booking.com/api/company/07ce8f7c-f3d3-4df2-84bd-33f8fc263deb/rooms/{room.id}/bookings";
                HttpClient BookingClient = new HttpClient();
                string BookingResponse = await BookingClient.GetStringAsync(booking);
                List<Bookings> bookings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bookings>>(BookingResponse);
                room.Bookings = bookings;

                string id = room.id;
                string name = room.name;
                int seats = room.seats;
                Uri Img = room.ImageUrl;
                List<Roomattribute> roomattrib = room.roomAttributes;

                var NewRoom = new Room
                {
                    RoomID = id,
                    RoomName = name,
                    FrontImage = Img,
                    Seats = seats,
                };

                 foreach (var books in bookings)
                {
                    string note = books.note;
                    DateTime TimeFrom = books.timeFrom;
                    DateTime TimeTo = books.timeTo;
                    Class2 BookRoom = books.room;
                    string BookId = books.id;

                    DateTime Now = new DateTime(2018, 04, 25, 09, 40, 00);

                    var BeforeEnd = books.timeTo.Subtract(Now).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
                    var BeforeBegin = books.timeFrom.Subtract(Now).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));

                    if (books.timeFrom <= Now && books.timeTo > Now)
                    {
                        ToRed();
                        DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                        ColorTimer.Interval = BeforeEnd;
                        ColorTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            ToYellow();
                            ColorTimer.Stop();
                        };
                        ColorTimer.Start();
                    }

                    else if (books.timeTo == Now)
                    {
                        ToGreen();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                        ColorTimer.Interval = BeforeBegin;
                        ColorTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            ToYellow();
                            ColorTimer.Stop();
                        };
                        ColorTimer.Start();
                    }
                }

                foreach (var attri in roomattrib)
                {
                    int attriId = attri.id;
                    string attriName = attri.name;
                    int attriIcon = attri.icon;

                    if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id == 1))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Tv = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id != 1))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Tv = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }

                    if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id == 2))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Wifi = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id != 2))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Wifi = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }

                    if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id == 3))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Projector = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id != 3))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Projector = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }

                    if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id == 4))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Wboard = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else if (room.roomAttributes.Any(a => a.id != 4))
                    {
                        NewRoom.Wboard = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }

                }

                Rooms.Add(NewRoom);
            }
        }
```

Right now all of my code is working perfectly (Apart from that the all bookings goes to all of the rooms but that is off topic...) and when a room is unoccupied it has a green `LinearGredientBrush` and when a room gets booked it is changing color to red and when it is 15 min until the room is unoccupied the color is changing to yellow.

What I need the check for is for example if a room is canceled before the time runs out.

I was thinking that put all of this in a `For loop` could be a solution:

```
var BeforeEnd = books.timeTo.Subtract(Now).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
var BeforeBegin = books.timeFrom.Subtract(Now).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));

if (books.timeFrom <= Now && books.timeTo > Now)
{
     ToRed();
     DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
     ColorTimer.Interval = BeforeEnd;
     ColorTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
     {
         ToYellow();
         ColorTimer.Stop();
     };
     ColorTimer.Start();
 }

 else if (books.timeTo == Now)
 {
     ToGreen();
 }

 else
 {
     DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
     ColorTimer.Interval = BeforeBegin;
     ColorTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
     {
          ToYellow();
          ColorTimer.Stop();
     };
     ColorTimer.Start();
  }
```

I hope I described the question well enough, and would be very pleased to get some help with my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as @Martin Zikmund said, just create a `DispatcherTimer` and set a interval(this is the rate to loop the info) to make this timer's `Tick` event trigger, then you should be able to loop the bookings info and change the xaml display in the Tick event.  Have you have a  try?

Comment: Yes I have tried but how do I get a infinity loop? cause it should check everything every minute :) @BreezeLiu-MSFT

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a `DispatcherTimer` for each booking separately, you could just create a single one that is triggered once per a time interval, for example once per minute (depending on how often you want to see the color changes).

In the `Tick` handler, you could then just check for each room:

- **A booking is active: Red** - this check can be done by a simple `foreach` loop over the bookings on the given room
- **A booking is starting in less than 15 minutes: Yellow** - again a simple `foreach` loop, check the start times of all bookings, if one is less than 15 minutes away, we have a match
- **Otherwise: Green**

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I understand what you mean but I don't really understand where to put these `foreach` loops... and the real problem was with how to write the checks :)

Answer (score 1):

The [DispatcherTimer.Tick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick) event fires after the time specified in **Interval** has elapsed. **Tick** continues firing at the same Interval until the **Stop** method is called, the app terminates, or the app is suspended (fires Suspending). So you can put the loop here and specify the internal is one minute.

Besides, if you want your app can run while minimized or under the lock screen, you can use extended execution to achieve it. See the topic [Postpone app suspension with extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution).

---Update---

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get current managed thread ID
    Debug.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    timer.Tick += async (ob, arg) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
    //You can update the booking room color here
    //TODO get data and update room color

    //You can also update the booking room color using Dispatcher.RunAsync method. 
    //This is alternative to update the data on the Tick event above TODO part directly .

        //await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        //{
        //    Debug.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
        //    //TODO get data and update room color
        //});
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

You can see the [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority, DispatchedHandler)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) Method.

Comment: ok, so what you mean is that I just need to make like a function and ad a async timer inside it without a stop, and set the interval to 1 minute, and it should loop forever? :)

Comment: Yes, the Tick event will loop if your app does not terminates or suspends while you don't call the stop method.

Comment: As what I test, the timer runs on the same thread as the UI thread, you can get the booking data again from your server then change the room color in the Tick event handler. I will provide the code in my reply update part.

Comment: ooh okey, so the solution could be calling he method I use to get all the data? :)

Comment: If your server could provide you the changed item data, it would be better to just get the changed items data then change their room color. But if not, calling the method you used to get all the data would also be a solution.

Comment: Ok so now it works! Just cause i'm so curious, what toes that `Dispatcher.RunAsync` do?

Comment: This should be another issue about `Dispatcher.RunAsync`. In your this issue, you can ignore the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` part in your app and just add the update data code in the Tick event hander. Since we can only update the UI control state in the UI thread, The `Dispatcher.RunAsync` is for scheduling work on the main UI thread to update the xaml control state. I will edit my update part to make it clear.

Comment: I just think that scheduling work on the main UI thread can be good, because I have other timers running on the UI thread. or is that unnecessary ?

Comment: As my above reply, the timer runs on the same thread as the main UI thread, using a Dispatcher.RunAsync is unnecessary, if you want, it does not matter. But if the thread is not in the UI thread, you must use Dispatcher.RunAsync to update the Xaml content.